# Issue with SelectList - NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-3.5, razor-pages

I have set up a SelectList to select an album when creating a track for the chinook database. Following Microsoft docs instruction, for some reason (that I can't see as I'm still trying to learn) it doesn't like what I am putting in my view on razor pages. The code for the walk through is below.

Entities:

```
public class Album
{        
    public int AlbumId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int ArtistId { get; set; }

    //related entities
    public virtual ICollection<Track> Tracks { get; set; }
    public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }

}

public class Track
{
    public int TrackId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int AlbumId { get; set; }
    public string Composer { get; set; }
    public int Milliseconds { get; set; }
    public int Bytes { get; set; }
    public double UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public int MediaTypeId { get; set; }
    public int GenreId { get; set; }

    //related entities

    public virtual Album Album { get; set; }

}
```

Creating the model for SelectedList:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using UWS.Project;

namespace Project.Pages.Albums
{
     public class AlbumPageModel : PageModel
     { 
        public SelectList AlbumNameSL { get; set; }

        public void PopulateAlbumsDropDownList(Chinook db,
        object selectedAlbum = null)
        {
           var albumsQuery = from a in db.Albums
                                  orderby a.Title // Sort by name.
                                  select a;

           AlbumNameSL = new SelectList(albumsQuery,
                       "AlbumId", "Title", selectedAlbum);
        }
     }
 }
```

Now my Model for creating the track:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using UWS.Project;

namespace Project.Pages.Albums
{
    public class TrackCreateModel : AlbumPageModel
    {
        private Chinook db;
        public TrackCreateModel(Chinook injectedContext)
        {
            db = injectedContext;
        }

        public IActionResult OnGet(int? id)
        {
            PopulateAlbumsDropDownList(db);
            return Page();
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public Track Track { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            var emptyTrack = new Track();

            if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<Track>(
                 emptyTrack,
                "track",   // Prefix for form value.
                 s => s.AlbumId, s => s.Name, s => s.Composer, s => s.Milliseconds, s => s.Bytes, s 
=> s.MediaTypeId, s => s.GenreId, s => s.UnitPrice))
            {
                db.Tracks.Add(emptyTrack);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToPage("./Index");
            }

            // Select AlbumId if TryUpdateModelAsync fails.
            PopulateAlbumsDropDownList(db, emptyTrack.AlbumId);
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to implement the SelectList in my view:

[image: I have marked the code where the issue is - the rest of the html is just to get the rest of the data but that looks fine.]

Being new to this I cannot for the life of me see the issue. I have looked at previous issues on here with SelectedList's but none relate to my issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What the type of Track.AlbumId ?Maybe the type of Track.AlbumId is different from the selected value,and you will get validation error.

Answer (score 0):

Do not enter selectedValue in the `PopulateAlbumsDropDownList` method in `AlbumPageModel`

Currently you either leave it blank or provide an id, but that's not going to work anyway

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I can't post comments yet because of my reputation. I try to follow the rules, but how should I have done this?

Comment: I commented out the selectedAlbum from the SelectList paramater and it now shows the list, which is good progress! Now I have the issue, when I select an album to add the track to, there is a validation error showing - 'The value '1' is invalid'. I don't understand how it can be invalid if I'm selecting it from a list?

Comment: Try changing your ```asp-for="Track.AlbumId"``` at your ```select``` to ```asp-for="Track.Album"``` and the same for the ```span``` with ```asp-validation-for```

Comment: It doesn't like that either - it just doesn't create anything with no AlbumId there. When AlbumId is there - it creates the whole record but just not the AlbumId.

Comment: Hmm okay, when or where exactly does this error occur?